# Laravel Artisan event:generate command throwing a Fatal error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm following the official documentation for Laravel 5.7 on the events registration and generation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events#generating-events-and-listeners

I have an `EventServiceProvider` with the following events defined:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * The event handler mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\FormBeforeCreate' => [
            'App\Listeners\WebhookBeforeCreate',
        ],
        'App\Events\FormAfterCreate' => [
            'App\Listeners\NotifyAfterCreate',
            'App\Listeners\WebhookAfterCreate',
        ],
        'App\Events\FormBeforeUpdate' => [
            'App\Listeners\WebhookBeforeUpdate',
        ],
        'App\Events\FormAfterUpdate' => [
            'App\Listeners\NotifyAfterUpdate',
            'App\Listeners\WebhookAfterUpdate',
        ],
        'App\Events\FormBeforeDelete' => [
            'App\Listeners\WebhookBeforeDelete',
        ],
        'App\Events\FormAfterDelete' => [
            'App\Listeners\NotifyAfterDelete',
            'App\Listeners\WebhookAfterDelete',
        ],
        'App\Events\FormBeforeSave' => [
            'App\Listeners\WebhookBeforeSave',
        ],
        'App\Events\FormAfterSave' => [
            'App\Listeners\NotifyAfterSave',
            'App\Listeners\WebhookAfterSave',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The subscriber classes to register.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $subscribe = [
        'App\Listeners\UserEventSubscriber',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any other events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }
}
```

## **The error:**

When I run the command `php artisan event:generate` I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function listens() on null in /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/EventGenerateCommand.php on line 35

                                                           
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Call to a member function listens() on null
```

According to the doc, it should do this:

> This command will generate any events or listeners that are listed in
> your EventServiceProvider. Events and listeners that already exist
> will be left untouched

I don't understant what I've missed since I didn't find any similar error by searching the web

Comment: laravel 5.7?? you might be looking at the wrong laravel version

Comment: Yes it is a big old project and we're still in 5.7. But the 5.7 docs (linked in my question) shows that this command should work fine

Comment: Remove all the listeners / events, run the command again, then re-add one-by-one?

Comment: @GilesBennett I tried re running the command with an empty EventServiceProvider, same error :/

Comment: please post the entire EventServiceProvider

Comment: Can you reset your EventServiceProvider to a [blank slate](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.7/app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php), then try the command? If that works, then try adding things back in one-by-one.

Comment: @aynber Exact same error with the file copy pasted from your link

Comment: The line number doesn't match up what's showing on https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php . Make sure the file matches. You may need to run `composer update`, or delete the vendor file and run `composer install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it seems like I was really tired yesterday night, Our project runs on Docker, I was running the command outside of the docker instead of inside.

I have no idea why it showed this bug in particular but once I ran the command in the docker all files generated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is the line that is returning `null`:

```
$providers = $this->laravel->getProviders(EventServiceProvider::class);
```

therefore, there are some problems with your `EventServiceProvider`... please, try using this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\FormBeforeCreate' => [
            'App\Listeners\WebhookBeforeCreate',
        ],
        'App\Events\FormAfterCreate' => [
            'App\Listeners\NotifyAfterCreate',
            'App\Listeners\WebhookAfterCreate',
        ],
        'App\Events\FormBeforeUpdate' => [
            'App\Listeners\WebhookBeforeUpdate',
        ],
        'App\Events\FormAfterUpdate' => [
            'App\Listeners\NotifyAfterUpdate',
            'App\Listeners\WebhookAfterUpdate',
        ],
        'App\Events\FormBeforeDelete' => [
            'App\Listeners\WebhookBeforeDelete',
        ],
        'App\Events\FormAfterDelete' => [
            'App\Listeners\NotifyAfterDelete',
            'App\Listeners\WebhookAfterDelete',
        ],
        'App\Events\FormBeforeSave' => [
            'App\Listeners\WebhookBeforeSave',
        ],
        'App\Events\FormAfterSave' => [
            'App\Listeners\NotifyAfterSave',
            'App\Listeners\WebhookAfterSave',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        //
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited to include my full EventServiceProvider. Still doesn't work with your code copy pasted..